# Delete log files automatically in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically delete files from webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460698/automatically-delete-files-from-webserver)

I'm logging some XML content to a text file using `file_put_contents()` in case I need it for debugging.

How do I delete this file after a certain amount of time?

I've got a restrictive `.htaccess` in the log folder, but I'd rather not leave the info (will have customer's addresses, etc) up on the web for long.

Comment: You have an error in your basic conception: log files should never be exposed publicly on the web. Just store the to some directory that is not accessible via HTTP on the server.

Comment: You can use a cronjob for this. More info [here](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)

Comment: You can use cron jobs even for cooking coffee. Is that an answer?

Comment: He asked how to delete the file after a while. I don't understand your down vote

Comment: http://pastebin.com/86Z8bDXS is all you need ....

Comment: Wow, so I was totally off base here.  Thanks everyone for setting me straight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, while agreeing with everyone else that you're using the wrong tool for the job, your question is pretty straightforward. So here you go:

- write a PHP script that will run from the command line
- use a tool like `cron` or windows scheduled task
- invoke the `cron` every minute/five minutes/etc

Your script would be pretty straightforward:

```
<?php
   $dh = opendir(PATH_TO_DIRECTORY);
   while( ($file = readdir($dh)) !== false ) {
      if( !preg_match('/^[.]/', $file) ) {  // do some sort of filtering on files
         $path = PATH_TO_DIRECTORY . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
         if( filemtime($path) < strtotime('-1 hour') ) {  // check how long it's been around
            unlink($path);  // remove it
         }
      }
   }
```

You could also use `find` if you're working in Linux, but I see that @Rawkode posted that while I was writing this so I'll leave you with his elegant answer for that solution.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it answers my question even if I was apparently asking the wrong question and generally doing it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should be using the PHP [error_log()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) function which will respect the php.ini settings.

```
error_log('Send to PHP error log');
error_log('Sent to my custom log', 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");
```

Comment: If I could accept 2 solutions I would also accept this for correcting my basic approach.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a built-in function – [`filectime`](http://php.net/filectime) – to track the creation date of your log files and then delete those that are old enough to be deleted.

This code searches through the *logs* directory and deletes logs that are 2 weeks old.

```
$logs = opendir('logs');

while (($log = readdir($logs)) !== false)
{
    if ($log == '.' || $log == '..')
        continue;

    if (filectime('logs/'.$log) <= time() - 14 * 24 * 60 * 60)
    {
        unlink('logs/'.$log);
    }
}

closedir($logs);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be handling your logging better, but to answer your question I'd use the *nix `find` command.

`find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -delete`

This will delete all files that haven't been modified in five days. Adjust to your own needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can work it out:

1. if you write the log to only one file, you can empty the file using something like this:

   ```
   <?php file_put_contents($logpath, "");
   ```
2. if you generate many files, you can write cleanup function like this:

   ```
   <?php
   $logpath = "/tmp/path/to/log/";
   $dirh = opendir($logpath);
   while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
       if(in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) continue;
       unlink($logpath . $file);
   }
   closedir($dirh);
   ```

Comment: putting an empty content seems so obvious now. #facepalm  Thank you for your 2 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a server Scheduled task (most known as Cron Job under *nix systems) to run on a regular basis and delete the left log files. The task would be to execute a PHP code that will do the job.

See [Cron Job Overvieww](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml)