# Clear error_log file with PHP

Tags: php, cpanel

Okay, so my error log files are getting filled up really fast due to some unfixable errors (they exist due to the site's design) and it's using up a lot of my webspace pretty fast.

However, I do not need the error_log files at all. I've been looking around and I cannot find a way to stop error_logs in cPanel, so I thought that perhaps I could run a script on each page a user visits that empties or deletes the error_log file.

Is this possible? the error_log file is in the document root of each of my websites

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347988/delete-log-files-automatically-in-php

Comment: Answers on there don't help

Comment: If you know where the error file is located on the server, and you have permissions to delete it, then just delete it..

Comment: Yes, but it comes back. I sorted the problem now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable error logging using corresponding php.ini setting:
http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors