# Automatically delete old files from a directory

Tags: linux

I have a folder in the /var/www/html directory of my webserver where jpg files are uploaded by the user. The files are named as the date and time they were uploaded. How can I store the last 20 images and delete any older image as new images are uploaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically delete files from webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460698/automatically-delete-files-from-webserver)

Comment: This one could also help: https://superuser.com/questions/268344/how-do-i-delete-all-but-10-newest-files-in-linux